# Finding eigenvectors of a 3x3 matrix -- can't tell if we need certain form of answer or not

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am given the matrix below and I have to find the eigenvectors. My question is about one of the eigenvectors and whether or not I found the correct answer.

Here's my work so far:

$\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 1 & -1\\1 & -3 & 0\\3 & -5 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

> $\begin{bmatrix}-2-λ & 1 & -1\\1 & -3-λ & 0\\3 & -5 &
>  0-λ\end{bmatrix}$
>
> So I went through, found the characteristic polynomial, did long
>   division to find the factors and got that I have repeated eigenvalues
>   of -2, and an eigenvalue of -1.
>
> I plugged in λ=-2 and got this (ignored last row).
>
> ${X_2-X_3=0}$
>
> ${X_1-X_2=0}$
>
> ${X_1=X_2=X_3}$
>
> And so I ended up with this eigenvector for λ=-2.
>
> $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$
>
> I plugged in λ=-1 and got this (again, ignored last row).
>
> ${-X_1+X_2-X_3=0}$
>
> ${X_1-2X_2=0}$
>
> ${X_2=-X_3}$ & ${X_1=2X_2}$
>
> And so I ended up with this eigenvector for λ=-1.
>
> $\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

This is from a practice exam and we haven't been given the answers so I can't really check (I used an online calculator to check my eigenvectors however).

When I used the online calculator, they had the eigenvector for λ=-1 as
$\begin{bmatrix}1\\ \frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{-1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$ .

**Is it necessary to divide all of the terms by 2? Do we have to have a leading value of 1? I just can't really tell if it's divided through by 2 just to simply for simplifications sake or if there's an actual point to it.**

Thank you for any & all help!

Comment: Sorry if anything looks weird, still learning MathJax and all the commands. Please let me know if I need to edit anything so it looks better!

Comment: Any non-zero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector. Whether or not you want a leading $1$ depends on what you’re planning to do with that vector. You might want a unit vector in the same direction instead, for example.

Comment: Personally, I would answer like you. I try  to avoid fractions if possible.

Comment: For your convenience, Greek letters are usually of the form `$\Lambda, \lambda$` for $\Lambda, \lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since if $v \neq 0$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $c \neq 0$ then $cv$ is also an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, you never have "uniqueness" of eigenvectors and you have some freedom in choosing the eigenvector that is appropriate for you. In general, I would "prefer" your eigenvector over the eigenvector suggested by the online calculator since it doesn't involve fractions but this is a preference that is more appropriate for a human to have than for a computer...

Sometimes there are reasons to do a specific normalization. For example, if you want to find a basis of orthonormal vectors then you can find $v$ arbitrary and then replace $v$ with $\frac{v}{||v||}$ to obtain a unit length vector.